# ¿Existe una palabra para la acción de "introducir costumbres o ideas que no son buenas y adoptarlas como buenas"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Estoy buscando una palabra similar a naturalizar pero con un significado un poco distinto. Naturalizar significa:

> Introducir en un país costumbres o palabras que son características de
> otro y adoptarlas como propias o naturales.

[Naturalizar](https://www.google.com/search?q=naturalizar%20significado&source=hp&ei=MppRYve9K_-H1sQPm5asyAo&iflsig=AHkkrS4AAAAAYlGoQlCbr5yXBduaCbJBfviJCn8kCDTM&ved=0ahUKEwj3noG5mof3AhX_g5UCHRsLC6kQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=naturalizar%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-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&sclient=gws-wiz)

En algunas situaciones se usa la palabra naturalizar para lo que quiero decir, pero no tiene el significado exacto de lo que se quiere transmitir.

Lo que busco es una palabra que signifique "introducir costumbres o ideas que no son buenas (en el sentido moral) y adoptarlas como buenas". O de forma más simple, hacer que algo malo sea visto como bueno.

La palabra abuenar existe (uno podría creer que a lo mejor tuviera este significado) pero aparentemente no tiene nada que ver. [Abuenar](https://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/abuenar)

> Crear cordialidad, buena disposición o voluntad en las relaciones con
> alguien.
>
> Hacer que algo o alguien sea mejor o esté en mejores condiciones.

¿Existe una palabra como la que estoy buscando?

Comment: conoZco (duele a los ojos ;-))

Comment: Sería más fácil con un ejemplo concreto. No creo que conozco el fenómeno. –

Comment: – No creo que conozcA el fenómeno – o – No conozcO el fenómeno – Tal como lo has escrito no existe en español :-))

Comment: Otra palabra que se me ocurrió es normalizar, está más cerca pero no es exactamente lo que busco. Ejemplo: Buscan normalizar el robo. Buscan naturalizar el robo. Buscan normalizar el ocupamiento. Buscan naturalizar el ocupamiento. Pero la palabra que busco es ir más allá todavía, de mostrar algo malo como su fuera algo bueno.

Comment: @Danielillo "No creo que conozco" la creencia es cierta.

Comment: Esa construcción no existe en castellano. Quizás en Tarzán ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Contaminar

> Transmitir [una persona] a otra una idea, un sentimiento o una actitud, en especial algo negativo.

### Pervertir

> Hacer que una persona adquiera vicios y costumbres moralmente reprobables.

### Malear

> Pervertir [una persona] a otra o hacer que se vuelva mala.

Comment: **y adoptarlas como buenas**.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy interesante tu búsqueda, pero probablemente no exista una palabra única, para destilar el complejo requerimiento de significar cosas tan específicas mediante un sólo término (`pervertir`, `corromper`, `contaminar`, entrañan la idea de una degradación o alteración maligna, pero les falta la aceptación, la adhesión semi-volitiva que tal manipulación ideológica opera en el sujeto receptor, de modo tal que incorpore como bueno algo malo´ —que es esencialmente lo que describes con el fenómeno de adopción o `naturalización` que nombras).

Entiendo que lo que describe fielmente el proceso de trastocamiento ideológico en la conciencia de terceros, de manera de que algo malo sea percibible como bueno — `infectando persuasiva y malignamente a otros` — es la expresión:

> **lavado de cerebro** [1](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavado_de_cerebro)

La misma refiere a formas de control de pensamiento o adoctrinamiento —conocida por sectas u otros grupos—, tendientes a domar la conciencia de una persona o colectivo humano.

> El lavado de cerebro, también conocido como reforma del pensamiento, adoctrinamiento o reeducación, consiste en la aplicación de diversas técnicas de persuasión, sean coercitivas o no, como la concesión selectiva de recompensas.[1](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavado_de_cerebro) Mediante esta estrategia psicológica, el domante obliga someter sus creencias, conducta, pensamientos y comportamiento a un individuo o sociedad, con el propósito de ejercer sobre ellos reconducciones o controles políticos, morales y cualquier otro tipo."

La expresión existe en inglés; [esta versión de wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainwashing) da cuenta de ese fenómeno (asociable a la influencia dirigida por la propaganda religiosa y afines)

> Brainwashing (also known as mind control, menticide, coercive persuasion, thought control, thought reform, and re-education) is the concept that the human mind can be altered or controlled by certain psychological techniques. **Brainwashing is said to reduce its subjects' ability to think critically or independently, to allow the introduction of new, unwanted thoughts and ideas into their minds,[1](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavado_de_cerebro) as well as to change their attitudes, values and beliefs**

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi punto de vista, la palabra la tienes delante de ti, si naturalizar consiste en "*Introducir en un país costumbres o palabras que son características de otro y adoptarlas como propias o naturales*" y lo que tu quieres decir es "*introducir costumbres o ideas que no son buenas (en el sentido moral) y adoptarlas como buenas*", la expresión más acorde seria a mi entender "**desnaturalizar las buenas costumbres locales**", ó simplemente, "**desnaturalizar las costumbres**", pues "desnaturalizar" tiene precisamente ese sentido de perdida, en este caso de las costumbres, hacer perder las cualidades de algo, añadiéndole algo, modificándolas, etc...

Los antiguos Griegos consideraban, cuando hablaban de las nuevas generaciones, y esto hace más de 2000 años, que la juventud degradaba ó estaba degradando las buenas costumbres, precisamente para referirse a esa noción de entrada de nuevas ideas, nuevas costumbres, cambio de moral, perdida de valores, siempre como aspecto negativo de la sociedad y con el mismo sentido que desnaturalizar, corromper, adulterar...lo existente. Más o menos como se sigue haciendo hoy en día respecto a las nuevas generaciones a pesar del tiempo trascurrido. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, la palabra más cercana a lo que se indica podría ser **extranjerizar**. De acuerdo con el DLE:

**extranjerizar**

1. tr. Introducir costumbres o elementos extranjeros en una cultura, lengua, etc., mezclándolos con los propios del país. El traductor extranjeriza su lengua. U. t. c. prnl.
2. prnl. Adquirir influencias extranjeras.